# FHIR Data Element with Multiple Data Types

Tags: hl7-fhir

To quote an example, for ‘DiagnosticOrder’ FHIR resource,

its ‘supportingInformation’ data element could support multiple data types:

Reference(Observation | Condition | DocumentReference).

During implementation/design stage, is it possible to select only one/some/all data types?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Technically, in this case there's only one data type - Reference.  (The list of allowed resources doesn't create new types, just asserts constraints against the one type.)  However, the answer is the same for elements that do allow a choice of types.  E.g. Patient.deceased[x].

Answer (score 1):

well, in some ways, yes.

when you are creating a resource to store of your own, or to send to someone else then you can select what you want to put in the resource.

If you're getting resources from anywhere else, well, that depends on what the other party selects, and then, what you're going to do with them - maybe you can ignore some things that they choose to do, or not.

So there needs to be a way for various trading partners to communicate about their choices. See [Profiling](http://hl7.org/fhir/DSTU1/profile.html) for further information.